# Not found iOS Simulator in Xcode6.4

Tags: ios, xcode

I updated Xcode version to 6.4.
Then I deleted all files in `/Users/my/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`.

At first it worked, but now there is no simulator I can switch except my iPhone.
Take a look a picture.

[image]

Once I deleted a device file:

```
/Users/my/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
```

during working simulator.

Is it a cause?
Anyone knows solutions?

Comment: Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Download all Components?

Comment: I got it, but there isn't iOS 8.4 though my Xcode version is 8.4. 
Where can I find and download iOS 8.4 Simulator?

Comment: Try downloading 8.3 and see if the 8.4 simulator comes back.  If not, delete and reinstall Xcode.

Comment: No, I couldn't file in spite of having installed iOS 8.3. I restarted Xcode finish downloading, and there is no simulator option except iOS device. I'll reinstall Xcode.

Comment: "Then I deleted all files in /Users/my/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices." Why?

Comment: Because I thought there are some logs and cache. I reinstalled Xcode, but it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all of your development devices are just not created.

To add devices you want to set the destination to, or output device, on the menu bar: **Window > Devices**. Then at the bottom left corner there is a **add** button, there you will **create a simulator**.

Comment: I could create following you! Thank you so much!